How to save time series in a dataframe created in an in r loop?
I have a daily rainfall time series in several rain gauges (in columns) and I am calculating some annual indices, such as precipitation amount on year (PRCPTOT). I used looping to generate the series with annual totals for each rain gauge and I need to save the results in a data frame by rain gauge.
how could I save it?
library(precintcon)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

#Creating a data.frame exemple using precintcon package
df=melt(daily,id = c("year","month"))
df$value2=df$value;df$value3=df$value;df$value4=df$value
colnames(df) <- c('year','month','day','RainGaue1','RainGaue2','RainGaue3','RainGaue4') 
head(df)

#Looping
ncol(df)
nproc = 4
cont = 1
#Data.frame with results
dfr = data.frame(variavel = character(nproc), 
                  SPI = numeric(nproc),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
# i = 2
for (i in 2:5) {
  
  print(i) 
  df2<-df[,-c(2,3)]#
  nome.var=colnames(df2[i])
  variavela = nome.var[1]
  dfr$variavel[cont] = variavela

TIM = TIM[,c(1,2,i)]
TIM = na.omit(TIM)
names(TIM) = c("Year","Month","Cd")
head(TIM)
df2=TIM
#Here I calculate the annual SPI (standard precipitation index). 
#I want to save the #results for the rain gauges that are in the columns, #in the same spreadsheet (see example below).
names(df2)[1] <- "year"
names(df2)[2] <- "month"
names(df2)[3] <- "precipitation"

df2=as.monthly(df2)
head(df2)

SPI=spi.per.year(df2, period = 12);SPI

  cont = cont + 1
  
}

#Save tests results
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(dfr, "Results.xlsx")


Example of the data frame I want as a result:


Instead of using a loop, the function summarize in the package dplyr (which supersedes plyr) can be used to calculate the sums in one line:
library(dplyr)

dfr <- summarize(df, across(starts_with("RainGaue"), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = T)), .by = year)

Giving you the data frame:
   year RainGaue1 RainGaue2 RainGaue3 RainGaue4
1  1976    1595.7    1595.7    1595.7    1595.7
2  1977    1263.4    1263.4    1263.4    1263.4
3  1978    1098.0    1098.0    1098.0    1098.0
4  1979    1130.0    1130.0    1130.0    1130.0
5  1980    1501.5    1501.5    1501.5    1501.5
6  1981    1224.6    1224.6    1224.6    1224.6
7  1982    1823.6    1823.6    1823.6    1823.6
8  1983    1753.8    1753.8    1753.8    1753.8
9  1984    1060.0    1060.0    1060.0    1060.0
10 1985     977.0     977.0     977.0     977.0
11 1986    1490.3    1490.3    1490.3    1490.3
12 1987    1255.9    1255.9    1255.9    1255.9
13 1988    1150.2    1150.2    1150.2    1150.2
14 1989    1490.9    1490.9    1490.9    1490.9
15 1990    1351.0    1351.0    1351.0    1351.0
16 1991    1027.0    1027.0    1027.0    1027.0
17 1992    1458.4    1458.4    1458.4    1458.4
18 1993    1211.2    1211.2    1211.2    1211.2
19 1994    1175.6    1175.6    1175.6    1175.6
20 1995    1509.0    1509.0    1509.0    1509.0
21 1996    1511.3    1511.3    1511.3    1511.3
22 1997    1693.7    1693.7    1693.7    1693.7
23 1998    1651.2    1651.2    1651.2    1651.2
24 1999    1540.2    1540.2    1540.2    1540.2
25 2000    1411.2    1411.2    1411.2    1411.2
26 2001    1119.5    1119.5    1119.5    1119.5
27 2002    1334.3    1334.3    1334.3    1334.3
28 2003    1022.0    1022.0    1022.0    1022.0
29 2004     996.4     996.4     996.4     996.4
30 2005    1417.0    1417.0    1417.0    1417.0
31 2006    1023.8    1023.8    1023.8    1023.8
32 2007    1415.5    1415.5    1415.5    1415.5
33 2008     921.0     921.0     921.0     921.0
34 2009    1503.5    1503.5    1503.5    1503.5
35 2010    1237.4    1237.4    1237.4    1237.4


But it dosen't work for another precipitation index

@Marcel Yeah, it wouldn't. That's because spi.per.year only works on a data frame with columns specifying the year and month, whereas summarize feeds sum a vector, so if you just swap in spi.per.year for sum it will get fussy.

@Marcel I see you've edited your original question, but it's not going to show up in people's feeds since it's from a while ago and already has an answer. I'd suggest posting a new question instead so people will see it, and making it clear that you want to calculate SPI using spi.per.year (doing that will require a slightly different approach than your original question did), and also cleaning up your code so that it will run (right now, it throws an error since TIM and count are not defined).
